# Prestashop ModuleAdminController use simple template

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Trying to figure out why something like the below cant work.  There is a tab in the preferences admin section that points to this controller but when going to it it always output a blank page.  I have tried several things but the below is basically what I need.  There is no MODEL... I simply need this to get the uploaded file for postProcessing...

The controller file...

```
class AdminAstroImporterController extends ModuleAdminController {

    public function initContent() {
        parent::initContent();
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'import.tpl');

    }

    public function postProcess() {
        //do something here

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you find out whats wrong?

Comment: yes I will post the details as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can overide the actual content output by doing as shown in the initContent() function shown below.  The 'content' in the smarty assign can be any html you generate yourself.

```
class AstroImporterAdminController extends AdminController {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    //load current settings
    $this->data = unserialize(Configuration::get('ASTRO_IMPORTER'));
}

public function initContent() {
    parent::initContent();

    $this->show_toolbar = false;
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'content' => $this->renderSettings().$this->renderForm().$this->displayFields(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```
public function renderList()
{
    global $currentIndex, $cookie;

    $smarty = $this->context->smarty;

    $smarty->assign('currentIndex', $currentIndex);


    return $this->context->smarty->fetch($this->getTemplatePath().'/main.tpl');
}
```

Although its dirty as hell, it seems cleaner than Amb3rL4nn answer.

In v1.4 it was very easy to create a tab (and easy to find documentation) I wonder why they changed it and didn't supply an docs.

Comment: The solution I provided is passing back a string/html directly into 'content' portion of the page.  Yours is better if you are able to use a tpl file to generate the view.  If not, that is a way to force something into the content area.  I can't remember since it was so long ago but I think if you do not have a data model, then after the initContent call it would throw an error which was also an issue.